# Acciones Rapidas en el menu de seleccion de Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent, jetpack-compose

Estoy intentando establecer una acción determinada de mi app cuando se seleccione un texto fuera de mi app, según eh visto otras aplicaciones muestran sus propias acciones determinadas cuando se selecciona un texto fuera de ellas o con su app cerrada, yo desearía saber como se puede implementar eso, eh buscado pero no doy con la implementación, alguien puede ayudarme? Uso Android Studio (última version) con Jetpack Compose.
Ahi en la foto muestro dicho menu.

Muchas gracias de antemano![image: Ahi estoy mostrando el menu de acciones rapidas]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: En la foto se ve lo que explicó en la pregunta, es añadir una acción a cuando seleccionas el texto,  como por ejemplo sale Vía